# My AdMob banner is not displaying when I use my Id

Tags: android, dependencies, admob, display, banner

When I put the test banner id it displays well, but when I put mine nothing is displayed (I have a lot of requests but 0 impressions).

It's been two weeks since I set up my Admob account and it's been verified.
I've been looking for hours and I can't find any solutions.

Here is my .xml code :

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

The Manifest:

```
<application
  <meta-data
   android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
   android:value="ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXX~YYYYYYYY"/>
  <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
```

Java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private AdView mAdView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cocktail);

        MobileAds.initialize(this);
        mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

And the Gradle file :

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'


    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.7'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.1.0'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:19.1.0'
}
```

Is the problem coming from my code or from AdMob?

Thanks

Comment: Hi @Matteo, I'm having the same issue. When I switch my ID from the test ad units to a real one, nothing shows. If anyone has any insight on this please comment/answer.

Comment: No problem, keep me in the loop as well.

Answer (score 0):

when you want to create an ad block, you are asked if you want to check this: "Partner Auctions", do not check.
And everything will be fine.
[image: ...]